# systemd-resolve seems to not query the specified DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved

Edit: during the time it took me to type out this question it apparently fixed itself, it now works as intended. I'm still interested in as to why this could have happened :)

My Setup is as follows:

I have a local DNS Server (pihole to be precise) at address `192.168.1.200`.
I also have a server in my home network at address `192.168.1.300`.
My domain `example.com` points to my public IP `5.5.5.5`.
The pihole has some custom DNS entries, so that when I'm within my local network, `example.com` is resolved to `192.168.1.300` instead of `5.5.5.5` (to avoid problems with NAT)
I have set the DNS Server for my wifi to `192.168.1.200`. (It's also set in the router...)

Now somehow, I still get the 5.5.5.5 IP from systemd-resolve.

I have flushed the DNS cache with
`sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`

`sudo systemd-resolve --statistics` returns a cache size of 0

`systemd-resolve --status | grep "DNS Servers"` shows `192.168.1.200`

**Now comes the interesting part:**

`dig example.com` returns `5.5.5.5`

while
`dig example.com @192.168.1.200` returns `192.168.1.300`

How is that possible? How do I get systemd-resolve to actually query the DNS server I have set?

some more information:

- `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` returns
  `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep 26  2019 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`
- `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returns

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search home
```

- `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*` returns

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-==================================================
un  dnsmasq                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base           2.79-1           amd64            Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
un  dnsmasq-base-lua       <none>           <none>           (no description available)
```

- `grep -i dns /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` returns

```
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved my problem was to run `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart`